# Information from another activity

Tags: java, android

I've been searching my problem but i can't find anything that helps my case.
I have an activity with a ListView where you can see names of people in a Database and when you click in one of the name it should go to another activity to show the details but it crashes when i click the name. Code above:

First Activity:
 Code that shows all the names in ListView is working

```
myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", 3000).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_vertodos);
            lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listone);
            Cursor cursor=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM teste;", null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nome:", 3000).show();
                data.clear();
                do{
                    data.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());   
                ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA NOT AVAILABLE", 3000).show();
                }
            cursor.close();}
    });


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String name = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    List<String> emailLists = new ArrayList<String>();
                    emailLists.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
                    String email = emailLists.get(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detalhes.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name",name);
                    intent.putExtra("email",email);
                    startActivity(intent);  
                }
            });
```

My question is now. i created a second activity that get's the information but it's giving an error:

Second Activity:

```
txname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnome);
    txmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmail);


    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(b!=null){
        String n =(String) b.get("name");
        String m =(String) b.get("email");
        txname.setText(n);
        txmail.setText(m);

    }
```

The first error is:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor

Comment: `l.getItemAtPosition(position)` is returning a `String`, not a `Cursor`. Also, you should call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 The first error is: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor
```

Issue is your trying to type cast the `String` to `Cursor` at this line

```
 Cursor detalhes = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

`getItemAtPosition` will return the data associated with the specified position in the list.

So, in your case your have passed  `List<String>` `data` as the data for the list items. so each item will have as string object

```
String name = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

If you need to pass the email of that items. You can create a ArrayList  for email and add it from database like this.

```
  List<String> emailLists = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And, add the emails into the list

```
 data.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
```

Now, When the item selected, get the email from the `ArrayList`

```
String email = emailLists.get(position);
```

Comment: i did that but then it gives me an error in getColumnIndex. Says its undefined for the type String.

Comment: Yes.You can't use getColumnIndex for String.  You have added only the name in the List. getItemAtPosition will return you the name

Comment: Thank you it's working. Now i have another question, i wanted to return also the email of that person, but he's repeating the name in both TextViews.

Comment: see, my updated answer. This is the only possible way, since you don't use custom adapter, and getItemAtPosition can only return String  since ArrayAdapter can hold only one Array List

Comment: See my update question onItemClicked. I did has you said and tried other things but when i click in the name to check the details it crashes.  One of the errors that i understand is:    Process: com.exaple.listview, PID: 2886
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: No. Its wrong. You need to add email to the list when you read from database.

Comment: add email to list, i'm not following?? Can you explain how do i do that?? Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are setting an `ArrayAdapter<String>` to your `ListView`, so in the following line, `l.getItemAtPosition(position)` returns a `String`, not a `Cursor`, and the cast fails.

```
Cursor detalhes = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: Ya that's right i have an ArrayAdaptar that return a String. Do you know a way to do this?